# Clipping Navigation Bar using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm at the end of my wits trying to fix this navbar

clipping here https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDFQK.png filling here https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aHv2.png

By those pictures, you can see that I use transform to create the rhombus (or to be politically correct, paralellogram) menu. I utilize ul and li in order to do that.

I want the end of the contact to be clipped, I tried using overflow but it doesn't seem to work. Is there anyway flexible to clip the last menu-item of the menu-bar? Or if there isn't, can someone please show me whether it's feasible to create a separate filler which will work together with the contact item-menu?

In explanation, when I hover the contact item-menu, the filler will also get into hover state. and the filler is needed to be adaptive to the browser size.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="outerwrap">    
     <div class="innerwrap">
         <div class="container">
             <div class="sixteen columns"> 
                 <div class="header">
                     <img class="scale-with-grid" id="logo" src="images/Logo-161x114.png" alt="Creative VistaIdea">
                     <div id="navbar">
                         <ul id="nav" >
                             <li class="rhombus"><a class="Home"     href="#"><span><p>Home</p></span></a></li>
                             <li class="rhombus"><a class="About"    href="#"><span><p>About</p></span></a>
                                   <ul>
                                         <li><a class="History"  href="#"><span><p>History</p></span></a></li>
                                         <li><a class="Board"    href="#"><span><p>Board</p></span></a></li>
                                         <li><a class="Vision"   href="#"><span><p>Vision &amp; Mission</p></span></a></li>
                                     </ul>
                             </li>
                             <li class="rhombus"><a class="Benchmark"    href="#"><span><p>Benchmark &amp; Market</p></span></a></li>
                             <li class="rhombus"><a class="Service"      href="#"><span><p>Service</p></span></a></li>
                             <li class="rhombus"><a class="Work"         href="#"><span><p>Work</p></span></a></li>
                             <li class="rhombus"><a class="Client"       href="contact.html"><span><p>Client</p></span></a></li>
                             <li class="rhombus"><a class="Contact"      href="index.html"><span><p>Contact</p></span></a></li>
                         </ul>
                     </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

and Here's my CSS:

```
#nav, #nav ul{margin:0px; padding:0px; list-style-type:none; list-style-position:outside;}

     #nav a:link, #nav a:active, #nav a:visited{height:31px; display:block; text-decoration:none; background: #1a1a1a; /* Old browsers */
                                        /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
                                        background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
                                        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1a1a1a 0%, #4d4d4d 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
                                        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1a1a1a), color-stop(100%,#4d4d4d)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
                                        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1a1a1a 0%,#4d4d4d 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
                                        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1a1a1a 0%,#4d4d4d 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
                                        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1a1a1a 0%,#4d4d4d 100%); /* IE10+ */
                                        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1a1a1a 0%,#4d4d4d 100%); /* W3C */
                                        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1a1a1a', endColorstr='#4d4d4d',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */}

     #nav a:hover                        {background: #2e3191; /* Old browsers */
                                         /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
                                         background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
                                         background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2e3191 0%, #1b75bb 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
                                         background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#2e3191), color-stop(100%,#1b75bb)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
                                         background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2e3191 0%,#1b75bb 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
                                         background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2e3191 0%,#1b75bb 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
                                         background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2e3191 0%,#1b75bb 100%); /* IE10+ */
                                         background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2e3191 0%,#1b75bb 100%); /* W3C */
                                         filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2e3191', endColorstr='#1b75bb',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */}

     #nav li ul {position:relative; display:none;}

     #nav li ul li a:link, #nav li ul li a:active, #nav li ul li a:visited    {height:31px;
                                                        background: #859dc4; /* Old browsers */
                                                        /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
                                                        background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
                                                        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #859dc4 0%, #8893be 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
                                                        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#859dc4), color-stop(100%,#8893be)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
                                                        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #859dc4 0%,#8893be 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
                                                        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #859dc4 0%,#8893be 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
                                                        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #859dc4 0%,#8893be 100%); /* IE10+ */
                                                        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #859dc4 0%,#8893be 100%); /* W3C */
                                                        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#859dc4', endColorstr='#8893be',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */ ;}

     #nav li ul li a:hover                                            {background: #b3b1b1; /* Old browsers */
                                                        /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
                                                        background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
                                                        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b3b1b1 0%, #818282 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
                                                        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#b3b1b1), color-stop(100%,#818282)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
                                                        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b3b1b1 0%,#818282 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
                                                        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b3b1b1 0%,#818282 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
                                                        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b3b1b1 0%,#818282 100%); /* IE10+ */
                                                        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b3b1b1 0%,#818282 100%); /* W3C */
                                                        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b3b1b1', endColorstr='#818282',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */}

.History{width:13%;float:left;}
.Board{width:13%;float:left;}
.Vision{width:13%;float:left;}

     li.rhombus
     {
    position: relative;
    transform: skew(-35deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-35deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-35deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-35deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-35deg);
    width:100%;
     }

     a.Home         {width:10.1553784860558%;float:left;}
     a.About        {width:8.9601593625498%;float:left;}
    a.Benchmark {width:20.1155378486056%;float:left;}
    a.Service   {width:9.5577689243028%;float:left;}
    a.Work      {width:10.5498007968127%;float:left;}
     a.Client   {width:10.5498007968127%;float:left;}
     a.Contact  {width:11.9482071713147%;float:left;}

     li.rhombus span 
     {
    transform: skew(35deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(35deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(35deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(35deg);
    -o-transform: skew(35deg);
    display:block;
     }

     #nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul ul{
    display:none;
    }
     #nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li li li li:hover ul{
    display:block;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are not opposed to adding an element to the last item, that is to say the menu is not dynamically created and you do not need to keep track of the what is the last element, then you can try adding a div into the last LI that can act as a back filler.

```
<li class="rhombus"><div style='position:relative;z-index:10;'><a class="Contact" href="index.html"><span><p>Contact</p></span></a></div><div class='clipper'></div></li>
```

CSS:

```
    .clipper{
        width:50%;
        height:100%;
        background:black;
        position:absolute;
        right: -17.5%;
        transform: skew(35deg);
        -webkit-transform: skew(-35deg);        
        -moz-transform: skew(-35deg);
        -ms-transform: skew(-35deg);
        -o-transform: skew(-35deg);
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

[Here is an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/zP4jm/3/)

Comment: Thank you, I've tried your solution and it worked perfectly. and even better, it also allowed to solve another problem on hovering. I tried creating another `<li></li>` to fill the open area but it disabled me to create an equal hover status when the filler was selected.

Your solution enables me to put the `<div></div>` inside the `<a></a>` tag soo.. killing two birds with one stone, I could solve the cavity problem and also solve the hovering problem.

Once again, thanks :)

Comment: A similar approach without changing the html would have been to assign a :after pseudoelement to the last child of the ul

Comment: @vals could you fiddle this for us? I would very much like to see what you are talking about. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Working on the Pow-lan answer, to do it without changing the html, I added to the CSS:

```
#nav > .rhombus:last-child:after {
    content: "";
    width: 29px;
    height: 31px;
    background-color: red;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 146px;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: skew(35deg);
    display: block;
}

#nav > .rhombus:last-child:hover:after {
    content: "";
    width: 29px;
    height: 31px;
    background-color: green;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 146px;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: skew(35deg);
    display: block;
}
```

Most of the code in the hover state is redundant, it should work just changing the color.
I have to admit that I have no idea why the right coordinate needs to be this value, I wonder that it comes from the skewing. I have set it by trial and error

the result is :

```
http://jsfiddle.net/vals/MV6CN/
```